# Prove stochastic differential relation $(dN_t)^2 = dN_t$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

I have some difficulties in showing the following problem. Any hints will be appreciated!

Show $$(dN_t)^2 = dN_t$$ for $N_t$ is the Poisson process

I have thought of two approaches, both were met with difficulties

Approach 1: Use previously proven relations:

I have $(dM_t)^2 = dN_t$, where $M_t$ is the compensated Poisson process - $M_t = N_t - \lambda t$ and $d_t\,dM_t = 0$. Also $dM_t = dN_t -\lambda dt$ so 
\begin{align}
(dN_t)^2 &= (dM_t + \lambda dt)^2 \\
&= (dM_t)^2 +2\lambda dt\,dM_t + {\lambda}^2dt^2 \\
&= dN_t + {\lambda}^2dt^2
\end{align}
So the remaining piece for this approach is for the $\lambda^2dt^2$ term to disappear. But will it necessarily disappear?

Approach 2: By definition.

Let $a < b$ and consider the partition $a = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{n-1} < t_n = b$ then I want to show $$\textrm{ms}-\lim_{||\Delta_n|| \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[\Delta N_k^2 - \Delta N_k] = 0$$ where $||\Delta_n|| = \sup_{0 \leq k \leq n-1}(t_{k+1} - t_k)$

I attempt to prove the above by showing $E[\Delta N_k^2 - \Delta N_k] \to 0$ and $\textrm{var}[\Delta N_k^2 - \Delta N_k] \to 0$

but was unsuccessful - so I am suspecting that approach 2 is off.

Thanks!

Comment: $ΔN_k=m$ with probability $e^{-λΔt_k}\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{m!}$. This should allow to easily compute expectation and variance. Or even more simple, in the limit one gets a Poisson distribution if one sets $ΔN_k=0$ with probability $1- λΔt_k$ and $ΔN_k=1$ with probability $λΔt_k$ so that $ΔN_k^2- ΔN_k=0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Ah yes, since $P(\Delta N_k^2 - \Delta N_k = 0) = P(\Delta N_k = 0 \cup \Delta N_k = 1) = P(\Delta N_k = 0) + P(\Delta N_k = 1) = 1$. However. by any chance would you know why I do not get the answer by approach 1?

Comment: One rough guess I have is that $dt \to 0$ since $||\Delta_n|| \to 0$

Comment: $dt$ is a symbol that stands for a zero sequence $\max_k(Δt^{(n)}_k)\to 0$. In the first approach you should get an error of the size $O(\max_k(Δt_k))$ which converges to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from where you ended, the random variables $ΔN_k$ are independent, and all are Poisson distributed with parameter $λΔt_k$ so that expectation and variance are additive.

Now we know from the definition of a Poisson process that $ΔN_k=m$ with probability $e^{-λΔt_k}\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{m!}$, so that
\begin{align}
\Bbb E[ΔN_k^2-ΔN_k] &= e^{-λΔt_k}\sum_{m=0}^\infty(m^2-m)\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{m!}
\\
&=e^{-λΔt_k}\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{(m-2)!}
\\
&=(λΔt_k)^2
\\
\text{and }~~
{\rm Var}(ΔN_k^2-ΔN_k)
&=e^{-λΔt_k}\sum_{m=0}^\infty(m^2-m)^2\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{m!} - (λΔt_k)^4
\\
&=e^{-λΔt_k}\sum_{m=2}^\infty(m^2-m)\frac{(λΔt_k)^m}{(m-2)!} - (λΔt_k)^4
\\
&\qquad\qquad\Bigl(\text{ and using }m^2-m=(m-2)(m-3)+4(m-2)+2\Bigr)
\\
&=(λΔt_k)^4+4(λΔt_k)^3+2(λΔt_k)^2 - (λΔt_k)^4
\\
&=2(λΔt_k)^2(1+2λΔt_k)
\end{align}
In both cases the sum over the full interval gives quantities that have bounds in multiples of $(b-a)\cdot \max_kΔt_k$. As these bounds go to zero with progressive refinement of the subdivision, one can conclude that the infinitesimal quantities $dN_t^2-dN_t$ are zero. This is a symbolic abbreviation for the fact that the quadratic variation of the Poisson process is the same process again.

Comment: Where do you get that the expressions can become negative? $λ$ and $Δt_k$ are all positive, and sums of their powers stay positive.

Comment: Oh my apologies! I missed out that they are squared terms.